# How to Use Opportunity to Setup Onboarding Journey for New Users SFDC Pro?

Tags: opportunity

I'm trying to setup opportunity funnel but this will serve more as onboarding process than a sales process. The only touch of sales person is to call new users.

Product is SaaS. Opportunity starts when they create an account then Closed Won for this is if user become a paid user.

I wanted to do Email Journey similar as to how Journey Builder does in SFMC. Is it possible to combine Opportunities with Flows?

So what I want to do is send emails automatically when they register for a new account. And then after a few days, create a new task for the opportunity owner so he will be reminded to call customer.

If you can link me to some articles, that would be helpful.